# Can't access Hangfire Dashboard using Authorization boilerplate code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

I can access the Hangfire dashboard from my local environment, but can't access it from a deployed server. Initial searches showed that I needed to enable authorization. So I have, according to very simple boilerplate examples.

First, I created this class where the `Authorize` method should force an approval:

```
public class HangFireAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context)
    {
        return true;

        //var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();

        //// Allow all authenticated users to see the Dashboard (potentially dangerous).
        //return httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

Then I added the configuration:

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
    Authorization = new[] { new HangFireAuthorizationFilter() }
});
```

But after I deploy and try to access the `/hangfire` page I see this in the logs:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery[7]
  An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
   ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {450e662b-997d-4b41-b70b-3290373a73a7} was not found in the key ring.
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.GetCookieTokenDoesNotThrow(HttpContext httpContext)
```

Could there be something else that I am not considering?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work, but the solution was unusual and did not match the [documentation](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-dashboard.html#configuring-authorization).

Moving the `DashboardOptions` object from the `UseHangfireDashboard()` method to the `MapHangfireDashboard()` method worked.

```
endpoints.MapHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
    Authorization = new[] { new HangFireAuthorizationFilter() }
});
```

Comment: You may have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67998307/1236044
IgnoreAntiForgeryToken seems be designed for your problem